# Fullscreen apps stealing the window/focus on startup

Tags: fullscreen

I like to use the fullscreen mode for as many apps as possible (Mountain Lion).

When I start my apps, they usually go into fullscreen mode but then grab the focus. I'd like to be able to essentially start fullscreen mode apps "in the background" and then switch to the window when I am ready to use the app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is annoying! Many forum posts mention the fix done by

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool NO
```

with restarting the Dock afterwards:

```
killall Dock
```

This, however, didn't work for my Yosemite 10.10.2 installation. Just thought I mention it here until some real answer comes.

[One of many sources.](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=496958)